# Google Analytics for iOS project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, google-analytics

I implemented Google Analytics in my project. For tracking a view, the tutorial says, I must do `#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"` and replace

```
@interface mainTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

to

```
@interface mainTableViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

I did that, but right now I do have some error like:

-'refreshControl' not found on object of type 'viewController *'

-Assigning to 'id _Nullable' from incompatible type 'viewController *const __strong'

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to track the view (to see the number of views) instead of Subclassing to `GAITrackedViewController` , you can keep the original class `UITableViewController` and use the following code to get the tracking work properly.

First import the below files.

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

You can now keep the original code.

```
@interface mainTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

In `viewDidLoad`, use the following codes

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName  value:@"Name of the Screen"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
```

If you get a error near `kGAIScreenName`, then go to `GAIFields.h` and then , add the following line.

```
extern NSString *const kGAIScreenName;
```

Hope this will solve your problem.